# How to View Execution Plan for Query Containing a Temp Table in Toad for SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, toad

I am trying to tune the performance of a stored procedure that contains a temp table in Toad for SQL Server.  After selecting "Include Actual Execution Plan" from the 'Editor' menu, I run the query.  The Results Set returns values as expected, however, the Execution Plan tab shows the following error:

```
Invalid object name '#temp'.
```

I have tried creating the temp tables first then just executing the SELECT statement that references it, I tried creating the temp tables as global temp tables and running the SELECT statement in another window, and I have messed with the SHOWPLAN_TEXT and STATISTICS PROFILE (as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822885/execution-plan-over-query-with-temp-tables) question) but I keep receiving the same error.  The only thing I have not tried is using a table variable, but the changes I will be making cannot be done on table variables, so this is not really an option for me at this time.

Has anyone else come across this or have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Stop doing it in Toad?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I would if I could.  It's the tool I'm stuck with at the moment.

Comment: Huh? Toad is the only tool you're allowed to use?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - You got it.  I have asked about using SSMS but have been told that I absolutely have to use Toad, no exceptions.

Comment: Well, I don't understand that logic. *shrug*

Comment: Can you use the command line?

Comment: @Metaphor - Command line from where?  Local machine?  SQL Server?

Comment: @PsychoBob It doesn't matter. Client or server. You want the ISQL command line utility, which is part of the SQL Server client package that should be on both client and server machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the ISQL command line utility on a machine that has SQL Server client package installed. Or any other utility that can submit a query to SQL Server.

[ISQL Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214007%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [How to get an execution plan (2nd part of the post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)